# Can't import Excel (xls) into Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I tried to import an Excel file (Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (*.xls)) into Power BI and I got this weird error.

```
Details: "Excel Workbook: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. The 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine 2010 Access Database Engine OLEDB provider is required to connect to read this type of file. To download the client software, visit the following site: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=285987."
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't let the "64-bit" part throw you off. Power BI has trouble working with xls files.

Simply save the workbook as an xlsx file and try again.

Comment: That is one solution, but Power BI can work with XLS files. It uses a different mechanism to read them than XLSX files, however, so you need to download and install the ACE provider from the link it gives you.

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced this problem. Simply I saved the data sheet as 'xlsx' file instead of 'xls' then it worked for me.

Give it a try!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also download Database Engine 2010 x64 [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

Click on download a select the X64 DB engine, then you will be able to work with .xls files on your desktop.
[image: X64 Db Engine]

Good luck!